# How to have text stay fixed with background image while scrolling?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a landing page that has the title of my site, a sub-header, and a button. I made the background image fixed with `background-attachment` so that it stays in place when you scroll up.

I want my title, sub header, and button to stay in place so the overview section will overlap it. I tried setting the text to be in a fixed position and making the `z-index: -1`, but it goes behind the background image and appears in the overview section. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmdzzz

The text is wrapped in the `intro-text` div

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  header .intro-text {
    padding-top: 300px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1
  }
}
```

Then I tried setting a higher z-index for the overview section

```
#overview {
  z-index: 1000; 
}
```

Comment: could you provide the html as well?

Comment: try `display:block` and `position:fixed`together.

Comment: `<div style="position:fixed;z-index:0;">subheader button</div><div page style="position:relative;z-index:1">site content</div>` without your structure, hard to guess if it is similar ...

Comment: Sorry forgot to put the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmdzzz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make position relative of your #overview. and set a background color. that means.

```
#overview {background-color: #fff;position: relative}
```

remove z-index: -1 from header .intro-text
Also I have created a pen for you. You can take a look on there.

http://codepen.io/bizedkhan/pen/eWpOaW

Answer (score 0):

Your **.intro-text** class must have a property:

```
position:fixed
```

In order to have stay fixed with the background image.